# python3 and c transfer data each other via socket

Tags: c, sockets, python-3.x

I want to send some control signal via Python3 socket to C. And I write a test case code to communicate. And what confused me is the server.c can't receive the signal from python3 and python can not display the data from C correctly. 
The server.c code is:

```
int main(){
        int serv_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        int clnt_sock;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
        bind(serv_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

        listen(serv_sock,1024);
        int  str[] = {1,2,5,6};
        char buffer[50];

        while(1){
                clnt_sock = accept(serv_sock,NULL,NULL);
                while(1){
                        send(clnt_sock,str,4*sizeof(int),0);
                        recv(clnt_sock,buffer,50,0);
                        printf("%s",buffer);
                }
                close(clnt_sock);
        }
        close(serv_sock);
        return 0;
}
```

and the client.py code is:

```
import socket
import struct
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1234
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host,port))
message = input("->")
while True:
        sock.send(message.encode())
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if not len(data):
                break
        for i in list(struct.unpack('iiii',data.decode())):
                print(i)
        message = input("->")
close(sock)
```

Any body had seen such problem before? Wish to get your help.

Comment: Show an example input and output case. Is it random or consistent?

Comment: You must do error checking at every stage. Once you do that. You will be able to find your mistake.

Comment: Reduce the problem: Check out `netcat`, which is a tool for making simple TCP transfers and use that as server or client side.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: that's good advice. It might be `nc` instead of `netcat` depending on the system. In fact I used nc/netcat to test the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here and there in your code, however, it's basically correct.

The client does not display data from the server because the `struct.unpack()` is failing. The value returned by `recv()` is `bytes` and so you don't need to decode it to unicode before passing it to `struct.unpack()` which expects `bytes` (or anything adhering to the buffer interface, which Python 3 `str` does not).

The server does receive the data from the client, but it's not displayed because of buffering. One way to fix that is to have the server print a new line after the message:

```
printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

Or the client could append a new line to each message:

```
sock.send((message + '\n').encode())
```

Or you could add `fflush(stdout)` after `printf("%s",buffer);` in the server.

There is an issue with the buffer in the server where part of an earlier message might appear in subsequent messages - you need to clear the buffer between each `recv()`. Adding

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

before the `recv()` should fix that.

Finally, it should be `sock.close()` not `close(sock)` in the client.

Comment: @qingming: glad that it helped you. The customary way to say thanks on SO is to upvote the answer if it was helpful (and if you have sufficient rep) and/or accept the answer if it solved the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers